# How to serve custom dns to dhcp clients in openWrt?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq, openwrt

I would like to serve custom DNS server to dhcp clients. How I can achieve that in openWrt?

Comment: This question is not too broad because it gets very specific answers. It's sad that basic idea of asking questions and getting answers is corrupted by policies abuse...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DNS server adress corresponds to DHCP option 006. 
According to the [OpenWRT Wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp#dhcp_option_example_to_set_an_alternative_default_gateway) your `/etc/config/dhcp` should look like

```
config 'dhcp' 'lan'
    ...
    list 'dhcp_option' '6,yourDNSIP'
```

Comment: Seems like you beat me to it by a few seconds, I'll leave my answer open as it is dnsmasq specific :)

Answer (score 8):

If you have dnsmasq enabled you need to use [DHCP-option 6](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dhcp.dnsmasq)

So in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` you would add:

> dhcp-option=6,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

To add the google DNS servers

Comment: What does option 6 do?  What are the other options (e.g. 1-5)?