# How to serve custom DNS server to DHCPv6 clients in OpenWRT?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, dhcp-server, dnsmasq, dhcpv6

[How to serve custom dns to dhcp clients in openWrt?](https://serverfault.com/questions/663364/how-to-serve-custom-dns-to-dhcp-clients-in-openwrt) explains how to serve custom DNS server for DHCP clients on IPv4.

But how to do it for IPv6? I tried adding DNS server's IPv6 address but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found it on the refered article https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp#dhcp_option_example_to_set_an_alternative_default_gateway

`list dns         "2001:910:800::12"` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom DNS servers by following the below link and

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp

```
list of strings (to list the strings)
```

list dns  "2001:4860:4860::8888"

list dns  "2001:4860:4860::8844"